# How to make dynamic logical statements in memsql?

Tags: sql, singlestore

I am trying to figure out if there is a way of creating a query that is composed of dynamic logical statements (AND and OR operators) in a configurable and persistent manner.
say I want to make a set of events and bundle them under an entity called feature, so each feature is composed by events.

For example,
featureA is eventA and eventB,
featureB is (eventB and eventC) or eventD

I was suggesting:

1. making an S expression column, and save it under JSON column then parse it to query
2. creating the where clause by hand, then save it under a text column and run it later, with a view reflecting the data prettier

then, I realised I can't execute (like eval) stored strings as mentioned [here](https://docs.memsql.com/concepts/v6.7/prepared-statements/).

so it comes down to what I was trying to avoid which is running and manipulating everything via client side querying. I needed a pure sql solution for further use by our data analysts.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please dont tag MySQL when you are using MemSQL. I have removed the tag. You should tag only the relevant RDBMS.

Answer (score 2):

You can execute dynamic SQL statements with https://docs.memsql.com/sql-reference/v6.7/execute-immediate/, see that page for some examples (prepared statements is a different topic, I don't think it is related to what you are looking for).

You may also be interested in https://docs.memsql.com/concepts/v6.7/persistent-computed-columns/, which allows you to define columns that are computed as sql expressions from other columns - so you could define your features this way.